# Session Login- MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm creating an Access database to track production/machine downtime. I want it to be as user friendly as possible...

I want to create a log in page for the 4 different people that will be inputting data so that they don't have to keep putting in the same information (Name, Shift, Date) on each record of machine downtime they are entering . They all use the same account so the function to get the logged on Windows user would not work.

It's not really a security log but more of a session log in. Any advice is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Then I suppose you well need to have the users pick an ID from a combobox list. These users are inputting the Name/Shift/Date info from a paper login form? You want to carry forward this info to next New Record entry?

Comment: Yes, I would like a Modal Dialog to be displayed when they open the Access file, they would enter those 3 options and for each new record I would like those 3 options to carry over until they close Access.

Comment: Will require code (VBA or macro). More than one way to accomplish. One common approach is to open form bound to the destination table to a new record row, users input data and code sets DefaultValue property of each control. Those values populate each new record row until user either enters a new value or closes form.

Comment: If you want a variable to be stored and accessible until Access closes, use a `TempVar`. If you want to be really user-friendly and don't mind bad security, consider using the Windows login or computer name instead of any input, since that saves a step for the users.